# How to use JFrame to output file content in system console output?

Tags: java, swing, file, file-read

I am using `JFrame` Java Swing for a piece of code shown below:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String filename = (jTextField1.getText());
    if (filename.endsWith(".log")) {
        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(filename).useDelimiter(";");
        List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

        // while loop
        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
            // find next line
            String token1 = inFile1.next();
            temps.add(token1);
        }
        inFile1.close();

        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
        for (String s : tempsArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

This code works but it only displays the file name as the file name itself (e.g. If my file name = `lalala.txt`, the output in console would be `lalala.txt`) I have tried this code but it does not display the contents inside the file. How do I go about displaying the contents in the file while using `JFrame` as my GUI in my console output? My GUI consist of a text field which will display the file name and when I click the `jButton2`, I want the button to show the the content of the file instead of the file name by itself. It runs perfectly fine but it is not what I want for my output.

Comment: why do you write your file content into the system-console? add the lines into your textfield!

Comment: @MartinFrank A `JTextArea` would provide a better space for the text content of a file, or a `JEditorPane` or `JTaskPane` for formatted content (i.e. HTML or RTF).  But agree with the general point of your comment.  OP - don't mix a rich client app. with console based input or output.  Either make it a pure console app. or make a rich client desktop app. and do all the I/O using components (like text areas and text fields etc.).

Comment: So meaning I would have to use JTextArea instead?  Because the JTextField is just purely being used for display of the filename. I do have a JTextArea but that function in my code is empty. I initially wanted to use my JTextArea to show output but I just wanted to start from the console first. Now that you mentioned about not mixing a rich client app. with console based input or output, I'll have to find another way out. @AndrewThompson

Comment: yes - `JTextArea `would be of course be the better choice! - don't tell me, tell irlyh8coding ^^ haha =) and best surround your `JTextArea` with a `JScrollPanel` - no offense =)

Comment: *"I initially wanted to use my JTextArea to show output but I just wanted to start from the console first."*  Consider.. `File f = new File("the.file"); FileReader fr = new FileReader(f); jTextArea.read(fr, f.getName());`  See [JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
   new Scanner(filename).useDelimiter(";");
```

Which in turn is reading the data from the string `filename`. Instead use:

```
 new Scanner(new File(filename)).useDelimiter(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
    try
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("absolute path to your text file...")),"UTF8"));

        String buf;
        while ((buf = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(buf);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```